# Select-String -Pattern $variable issue

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a report by cross referencing two text documents. I have C:\formeremployees.txt and C:\shareaudit.txt. As you can guess the formeremployees.txt has a list of former employee usernames only. No Headers; only usernames. The C:\shareaudit.txt contains a list of every folder on a share with the ACL info on the same line next to the folder path.

Here was my attempt at creating a report that only lists the lines that have user accounts from the formeremployees.txt:

```
$Users = Get-Content C:\formeremployees.txt

foreach ($User in $Users) {
  $Output = Select-String -Path "C:\Shareaudit.txt" -Pattern "$User"
  $Output.Line | Out-File C:\completereport.txt -Append
}
```

But unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is an
empty string.
At line:7 char:71
+ $Output = Select-String -Path "C:\Shareaudit.txt" -Pattern "$User"
+                                                            ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand

Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is an
empty string.
At line:7 char:71
+ $Output = Select-String -Path "C:\ShareAudit.txt" -Pattern "$User"
+                                                            ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

Then I get a sad, empty completereport.txt file. I can't seem to get this to work or know if it's possible.

Edit________________________

Here's what else I've tried and the results:

```
$Users = Get-Content C:\formeremployees.txt|?{!([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($_))}

foreach ($User in $Users) {
  $Output = Select-String -Path "C:\Shareaudit.txt" -Pattern "$User"
  $Output.Line | Out-File C:\completereport.txt -Append
}
```

This gave me a blank C:\completereport.txt document.

```
$Users = Get-Content C:\formeremployees.txt|?{!([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($_))}
$Pattern = ($Users|ForEach{[regex]::escape($_)}) -join '|'
Get-Content "C:\Shareaudit.txt" | Where{$_ -match $Pattern} | Set-Content C:\completereport.txt
```

This as far as I can tell didn't do anything. There was no completereport.txt document created when it finished.

```
$Users=(Get-Content C:\formeremployees.txt) -ne ''

foreach ($User in $Users) {
  $Output = Select-String -Path "C:\Shareaudit.txt" -Pattern "$User"
  $Output.Line | Out-File C:\completereport.txt -Append
}
```

This gave me a blank text document.

```
 $Output = Select-String -Path "C:\Shareaudit.txt" -Pattern "<single username from formeremployeee.txt>"
  $Output.Line | Out-File C:\completereport.txt -Append
```

When I put in a username that I knew still had permissions to some folders in the share and was also in the formeremployee.txt, the script worked as intended and gave me a list of the folders I needed so there's nothing wrong with the bottom part of the script, so I'm guessing something is up with the formeremployee.txt or the way I used the $Users variable.

To test further, I tried this:

```
$Users=(Get-Content C:\formeremployees.txt) -ne ''

foreach ($User in $Users) {
  Select-String -Path "C:\Shareaudit.txt" -Pattern "$User"
}
```

This didn't output any results. The text formeremployee.txt file lists the usernames as follows:

```
username1
username2
username3
username4
```

Is it in the wrong format for this?

Comment: Check if there actually are empty elements: `foreach ($User in $Users) { "-$User-" }`

Comment: This listed the users as: 
-username
-
-username1
-
-username2
-

Comment: Those elements would not produce the error you said you're getting. Please provide sample input data that would allow us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Same error and none of these have worked for me.  I'm using a single regex, and it outputs from the variable.  However, if I try it as a pattern, I get this error "because it is an empty string".  And get this, if I try to $regexvar | gm, I get an error that "You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet."  Has anyone actually solved the problem of why an assigned var looks like an empty string in 'pattern'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious answer is that you have blank lines in your FormerEmployee.txt file. The simplest solution is to update your first line:

```
$Users = Get-Content C:\formeremployees.txt|?{!([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($_))}
```

What I would probably do to speed things up is make a regex pattern out of the users, and run the `Select-String` once, instead of once per user:

```
$Users = Get-Content C:\formeremployees.txt|?{!([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($_))}
$Pattern = ($Users|ForEach{[regex]::escape($_)}) -join '|'
Get-Content "C:\Shareaudit.txt" | Where{$_ -match $Pattern} | Set-Content C:\completereport.txt
```

Comment: Why not `(Get-Content C:\formeremployees.txt) -ne ''`?

Comment: Will 'Set-Content C:\completereport.txt' create the file if it doesn't exist? I ran this to see if it worked. It's been running for about 2 minutes now, and there's no C:\completereport.txt file yet, but I'll wait until the script has finished. Thanks for the help though. I'm still learning and this gives me a lot to look into.

Comment: While I didn't get any errors using your script from above, a C:\completereport.txt file was not created with the results.

Comment: without sample data to replicate the issue it is difficult to troubleshoot any issues you are having.

Comment: I had spaces after each username in the formeremployee.txt file. Just replaced space with nothing and I got the report I needed. You were right in the first place and I wanted to give credit where credit is due. Rookie mistake on my end.